# Convert auto increment ID to 9 digit random serial number

Tags: php, math, encryption

I have a MySQL database with users. Every row has an unique auto increment ID (1,2,3...). Now I need to convert this to a unique and random looking serial number that I can convert back to the ID - all using PHP.

User ID's go from 1 to 99999999999 (INT(11)).

All serial numbers should have a minimum of 9 digits and never start with a 0.
Users should not easily be able to  figure out how to guess a working serial number.

Thank's :)

Comment: what about md5($userId . $salt)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since if there's a user with ID: 99999999999 , how can you convert a 11 digits string to just 9?
You must decide: Having a bigger serial number (11 digits for instance) or having no more than X members.

Comment: If the ID is to big for a 9 digit number it's ok to add digits to the serial. Doesn't have to be super secure so some simple math trick might do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some simple 'encryption'. Take a ('secret') prime `p` `27407` and `base` `17` (for example). Compute the multiplicative inverse `inv` of base mod `p-1`, `12897`. [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=17%5E-1%20mod%2027406) can do that for you.

Id to serial number

```
serial = id^base mod p
serial = 42^17 % 27407 = 24978
```

Serial to id

```
id = serial^inv mod p
id = 24978^12897 % 27407 = 42
```

This can be calculated quickly by [exponentiation bysquaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Only ids between 0 and 27407 can be used, (if not enough take a bigger prime number) and all have a unique invertible serial number.

To increase obscurity you can XOR the result with some value.

**It's not real cryptography**, just stupid [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), but will take most humans quite some effort to crack.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with some simple math as I doesn't have to be very secure and need to be a number only.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to use a hash function with a secret salt used as key

```
$secretKey = 'oh no nobody will guess this';
$userId = 312;
$serialNumber = hash('sha256', $secretKey . $userId);
```

The hash works one-way of course, so you will have to store the serial number in the DB as well, since you cannot compute the ID from a given serial number.

Comment: I need to be able to convert both ways. And it has to be a number only (hash won't work). Unless the ID is to big it should always be 9 digits as well.

Comment: sha256 will return 64 chars , shouldn't he use `crc32` which return 8 chars and then just add 1 digit?

Comment: crc32 is not cryptographically strong at all. You could just use `substr($hash, 0, 8)`, if you need only 8 chars. That's still a lot better than crc32 (unless performance is a major issue).

Answer (score 1):

I will not recommend doing what you are trying to do.

You see, `autoincrement` are generally done to represent to constantly avoid redundant data and still maintain **readability**.

So, instead update your database structure to store hash as well. The structure might be somethign like `id`, `hash`, `name` and so on.

In the hash, you can use any logic

```
$hash = sha1("secretanswer".$userid);
$trimmedhash = substr($has,0,9); //get a 9 digit random hash
```

Hashes are one way encryption and it is so for a reason also. Anyways, in order to verify the hash, you can do the same algorithm again

```
   $userid = "getthissomehow";
   $hash = sha1("secretanswer".$userid);
   $trimmedhash = substr($has,0,9);

   $prevhash = "asfaf23rfs"; //get previously stored hash somehow
   if($trimmedhash == $prevhash) { 
     //valid
   }
```

Comment: Where did the author say anything about updating database structure? All I can read about is that he wants to encrypt / decrypt the autoincrement in PHP, which apparently acts as middle-layer.

Comment: Would prefer to do it in PHP, need to go both ways and the serial has to be a 9 digit number (unless the ID is to big). Doesn't have to be super secure...

Comment: @dotmlj, Then trim the has down, `$trimhash = substr($has,0,9)`. Check the update

Comment: @N.B., I am making a suggestion. ;)

Comment: @Strax I need to be able to convert it both ways

Comment: @dotmlj, see the update again, may be it will get you the idea

Comment: This is really the only reasonable approach to the problem.  To summarize @Starx, generate a completely random 9-digit number then store it along with the original id somewhere in the database.  I know you want to do it completely in php but why?  And have you really thought through the entire process?

Answer (score 0):

First , Beacuse you want to be able converting it from X to Y and from Y to X , it CAN'T BE RANDOM. What can be done is just math manipulation, following the next steps:

1.Complete the length of ID to 9 with constant digits or digits from the ID itself.
Just a reminder: You can't use random digits! Otherwise it won't work both ways.

2.Do a math manipulation , like increaseing each digit by 1.
Notice that if this math action changes one of the digits completly it will be almost
impossible to get it back.
For example , if you're increasing each digit by 2 and there are the next digits: 8,9
you'll get into troubles unless you use a "carryover" method.
So I will recommend to increase each digit by X , but if DIGIT+X > 10 , leave it DIGIT.

3.How to convert it back? Simply , follow those steps backward.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very interesting problem. Hopefully I understood what you are looking for. Here is what i came up with:

```
$test_limit = 25;
$test_ids = array(1, 99999999999);
for($i=0; $i<($test_limit-2); $i++) $test_ids[] = mt_rand(1, 99999999999);

foreach($test_ids as $tii=>$ti)
{
  $serial = getSerialUsingId($ti);
  $id = getIdUsingSerial($serial);
  if($id!=$ti) echo 'Test '.($tii+1).' (id: '.$ti.') FAILED! (serial: '.$serial.")\n";
  else echo 'Test '.($tii+1).' (id: '.$ti.') was a success! (serial: '.$serial.")\n";
}


function getMask($index, $places=8)
{
  $masks = array
  (
    0xac976f4,
    0x1c70f81,
    0x441f67f,
    0x5fb0b87,
    0xf1542d2,
    0xfa28851,
    0x91bbd8c,
    0x30a5448,
    0x46a2708,
    0x5856fbf,
    0x65fa462,
    0xf24337b,
    0xea2c390,
    0x8561da4,
    0x9f77b25
  );

  if($places==4) return $masks[$index] & 0x0000FFFF;
  else return $masks[$index];

}// getMask


function getSerialUsingId($id)
{

  $prepend = '';
  $mask_index = mt_rand(0, 14);

  // 8 hex places can only handle up to 4294967295
  // If the number is greater than than that then get the additional bytes and treat separate
  if($id>0xffffffff)
  {
    $packed = pack('d', $id);
    $hex_pack = unpack('H*', $packed);
    $hex_string = substr($hex_pack[1],4);
    $bytes = array_reverse(explode("\n", chunk_split($hex_string, 2, "\n")));
    foreach($bytes as $bi=>$b) if(!$b) unset($bytes[$bi]);
    $truncated_bytes = array_splice($bytes,0,count($bytes)-4);
    $truncated = implode('', $truncated_bytes);
    $prepend = dechex(hexdec($truncated) ^ getMask($mask_index, 4));
  }

  $serial = dechex($mask_index+1).$prepend.str_pad(dechex($id ^ getMask($mask_index)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

  return $serial;

}// getSerialUsingId


function getIdUsingSerial($serial)
{
  $mask_index = hexdec($serial[0])-1;
  $serial = substr($serial, 1);
  $prepended = false;
  if(strlen($serial)>9)
  {
    $prepended = substr($serial, 0, 4);
    $serial = substr($serial, 4);
  }
  $id = hexdec($serial) ^ getMask($mask_index);
  if($prepended)
  {
    $unmasked_prepended = dechex(hexdec($prepended) ^ getMask($mask_index, 4));
    $bytes = array_reverse(array_merge
    (
      explode("\n", chunk_split($unmasked_prepended, 2, "\n")),
      explode("\n", chunk_split(dechex($id), 2, "\n")),
      array('00','00')
    ));
    foreach($bytes as $bi=>$b) if(!$b) unset($bytes[$bi]);
    $packed = pack('H*', implode('', $bytes));
    $unpacked = unpack('d', $packed);
    $id = $unpacked[1];
  }

  return $id;

}// getIdUsingSerial
```

Basically, the serial numbers are in hex, with the first hex digit determining which bit mask to use on the rest of the digits. This makes all serials 9 characters in length except when the id is > 4294967295 (0xFFFFFF) in which case the serial will have 4 additional hex digits which are also masked according to the first digit. Make sense? Hopefully it meets your very peculiar set of requirements or you can at least take this and make it work how you need it.

An example output of running the code:

```
Test 1 (id: 1) was a success! (serial: 60fa28850)
Test 2 (id: 99999999999) was a success! (serial: 24db649b1e87e)
Test 3 (id: 487808132) was a success! (serial: 31952aafb)
Test 4 (id: 227726272) was a success! (serial: 40869d847)
Test 5 (id: 836896236) was a success! (serial: 53ef7473e)
Test 6 (id: 958345007) was a success! (serial: 93d750827)
Test 7 (id: 164308905) was a success! (serial: 30d8ad1d6)
Test 8 (id: 715018588) was a success! (serial: 1205727a8)
Test 9 (id: 1127737044) was a success! (serial: 8403db29c)
Test 10 (id: 409934489) was a success! (serial: 81b654ed1)
Test 11 (id: 907129123) was a success! (serial: f3fe6ca06)
Test 12 (id: 720453497) was a success! (serial: b2cae9b1b)
Test 13 (id: 500526447) was a success! (serial: 1171c1b9b)
Test 14 (id: 322340582) was a success! (serial: 119fff012)
Test 15 (id: 1176988677) was a success! (serial: b4078c867)
Test 16 (id: 698755861) was a success! (serial: 92dcc0c1d)
Test 17 (id: 555569451) was a success! (serial: 52e0813f9)
Test 18 (id: 227332917) was a success! (serial: a0809bc8a)
Test 19 (id: 819326158) was a success! (serial: 334941ab1)
Test 20 (id: 659803411) was a success! (serial: d29f10e83)
Test 21 (id: 895574245) was a success! (serial: d3bc3a375)
Test 22 (id: 539979792) was a success! (serial: 425d47b97)
Test 23 (id: 933093554) was a success! (serial: 83497b4fa)
Test 24 (id: 959556569) was a success! (serial: 93d5b8cd1)
Test 25 (id: 668064949) was a success! (serial: 22616d334)
```